# Java program that separates the even and odd number of chars in a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to write a java program that separates the even chars in an `String` array. I made this program like this and it is working :

```
 String [] x = new String[5] ;
                 x[0] = "Hello" ;
                 x[1] = "My" ;
                 x[2] = "Name" ; 
                 x[3] = "is" ;
                 x[4] = "John" ;
                    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
                      if(x[i].length()%2==0) {
                        System.out.println(x[i]);
                          }
                       }
```

Now I wanna make the program work with a List declaration like this :

```
    List<String> list=Arrays.asList("HELLO","MY","NAME","IS","ALICE") ;
```

How can I continue from this point ? I TRIED with some sort of "for" iteration but I don't know how to recognize element by element from this List.

Comment: Please provide your desired output. That would be especially useful since you can't describe your requirements clearly.

Comment: do you mean seprate Strings with even length ?

Comment: if that is the meaning then you can do it in one line :
list.stream().filter(x -> (x.length() % 2) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enhanced `for` loop to the rescue

```
List<String> list=Arrays.asList("HELLO","MY","NAME","IS","ALICE");
for(String s : list) {
    if(s.length()%2==0) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

---

Also, just to point out, you can initialize that array as:

```
String[] x = {"Hello", "My", "Name", "is" , "John"};
```

which also supports enhanced `for` loop:

```
String[] x = {"Hello", "My", "Name", "is" , "John"};
for(String s : x) {
    if(s.length()%2==0) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This made exactly what I wanted . Thx man ! And also your array initialization is much better !

Answer (score -1):

you should run on each String a method that extract the even charachters and create from them a string like this :

```
public void printEvenChars(String str) {
    StringBuilder sbEven = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0) {
            sbEven.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sbEven.toString());
}
```

if you mean filter even legnth strings you can do it in one line

```
list.stream().filter(x -> (x.length() % 2) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think that was a title mistake

Comment: added an answer, based on the example he requested, but the title still confusing

Comment: Sorry if the title is confusing . I like your answer .